# Community Posts for Blog.SF?

Tags: discussion, blog

A lot of other sites are using blog.site.stackexchange.com to create a [blog on their topic](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) with contributions from the community.

The [Server Fault blog](http://blog.serverfault.com) has mostly been posts from George and I about running these sites and our experiences and thoughts in doing so. This was the [original intention](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/one-year-of-server-fault/) of the blog when it was created:

> You can expect to find blog posts there related to us documenting our
>   own efforts of running and scaling our network of websites — the same
>   sort of stuff you’ve come to expect from the server category on this
>   blog. We want to actively give back to the community by documenting
>   everything we’re doing on the sysadmin front — both by discussing it
>   on the blog, and asking (and answering!) relevant questions about it
>   on Server Fault whenever possible.

However, since other sites are taking a different direction, I'd be interested if the SF community would like to:

1. keep the blog the way it is so it sort of tells the story our site
2. keep it pretty much the way it is with the occasional guest post
3. see blog.sf become primarily a community blog

Now, if people would really like to see #3, that would come with the requirement that several top users are interested in  writing posts, taking the time review each others posts etc. For more on what would be involved see [Rebecca's post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/).

Comment: 4. Keep option 1 and have a community blog.

Comment: @Iain: That would be an option as well I guess, wonder what the domain name would be though.

Comment: community.blog.serverfault.com

Comment: @Iain. Or `serverfault.blogoverflow.com`, in line with the SE blogs? (Actually, that already exists, as a redirect.)

Comment: @TRiG: I'm not sure but I don't think blogoverflow existed in Aug 2011.

Comment: I think it'd be nice to see some community blog posts here on SF.

Answer (score 8):

I believe blog.serverfault.com as the voice of this particular sysadmin community has strong value, with updates on how the site works overall and meta-commentary on the site itself or the overall sysadmin community at large. For that, the occasional guest post would be a good thing. So, this is Option 2 for me.

We do have a couple of active bloggers around here, so keeping a separate community blog-site fed should be doable. I'd definitely contribute.

Comment: I'm all for occasional guest posts, or even adding the blog feeds that we pipe into chat as a sidebar of interesting posts, but I like blog.SF as an info-feed of what's going on with the StackExchange network -- SE is a good example of a medium-to-large / fairly high-traffic environment, and there's a lot of value to the SF blog just in presenting how you guys keep the environment running and improve it over time.

Comment: I would really like to see most the posts from your 'Nuances of the ServerFault FAQ' series cross-posted over to the official blog.  They are very much on topic, and some people might find them easier of they where on the official site.

Comment: @Zoredache I thought about pinging Kyle/George about it. If there is interest, I can clean those up better.

Answer (score 6):

I think that having a *dedicated* community blog is the right way to go. So ... basically Option 4, leave blog.sf about the site and how we do things "tell the story of our site" as Kyle puts it. Then, if the community wants maintain a blog we should set it up as a separate entity.

That said, if there isn't enough interest for a full on community blog (and they are a lot of work) then I would be open to occasional guest posts if someone wanted to talk about something. In particular I think something like [sysadmin1138's recent posts](http://sysadmin1138.net/mt/blog/) would be a good fit for the *occasional* community guest post.

Comment: I doubt there's enough interest to do Option #4; but I'm in favor of #2 too.

Answer (score 3):

People who want to blog already have blogs -- we're not in a demographic that doesn't know how to setup a blog if we so choose.  I'd only go so far as to suggest an aggregator of the blogs of active Server Fault users.

Comment: True. I gave up blogging once I started my family (no time for it any more), but I suspect most of us have tried blogging in the past.

Comment: Agreed. Anyone of us who can't easily set up a blog of our own should perhaps not even be here. Of course actually thinking of something to write...

Answer (score 2):

[I've previously suggested guest posts,](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/637/how-to-attract-more-professionals/644#644) so I'd say option 2 is the way to go.

[Sheesh! How many times is it going to ask me if I'm a human?  I've typed in about 10 captchas so far, is there a minimum answer length I've forgotten about?]

Answer (score 1):

I don't spend much time reading blogs so am more inclined to read one that I believe is actually relevant. i.e. On a blog related to SF I expect to read stuff relevant to SF, making option 1 my choice. However, if a mix was considered desirable I think option 4 is the way to go. Better to give people an easy way to filter what they read rather than have them ignore the lot.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience of posting on [the TeX.SX blog](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/), I'd say it is really nice to allow community members to post on such blogs, because of the public you reach. Sure, I have [my own blog](http://www.raphink.info/) which is well referenced and aggregated on [Planet Ubuntu](http://planet.ubuntu.com/) with a large audience, but for some topics, it's just much nicer to reach specifically a community of experts.

The blog posts I've made on the TeX.SX blog might not have interested many on my own blog, but they were interesting for the TeX.SX community. All the same, I'm currently thinking of blogging about [a new tool](http://search.cpan.org/~raphink/Config-Augeas-Validator-1.000/) to run unit tests against configuration files before you deploy them. I could very well blog about that on my blog, but I think more people would be interested in the SF community because it's specifically a sysadmin subject.

On the TeX.SX blog, we've also gotten in the habit lately of posting whenever a question on TeX.SX led to a new CTAN package. This could be something nice here too, if some questions lead to new projects, Perl/Python/other modules, etc.

So my choice would be 3. or 4. as suggested by Zypher.